# Arrange dataframe based on values on different columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, rows

**Input:** `df` as follows:

```
appl_id  CNET   CCON    SCORE   DER   TOL_TNW
863793   42.6   4       752     0.4   1.8
863487   0      1       761.5   0.6   2.6
863487   0      1       770     0.6   2.6
863283   0      NaN     691     1.9   7.3
863283   0      5       691     NaN   7.3
900555   NaN    NaN     650     0     NaN
```

**Output Seek:**

With respect to **appl_id**, **different values** in columns need to be **concatenated to list** and **retain if values are similar**.

```
appl_id  CNET   CCON    SCORE       DER   TOL_TNW
863793   42.6   4       752         0.4   1.8
863487   0      1       [761.5,770] 0.6   2.6
863283   0      5       691         1.9   7.3
900555   NaN    NaN     650         0     NaN
```

**I have tried with**

```
df.set_index('appl_id').T \
  .apply(lambda x: x.shift(len(x) - x.index.get_loc(x.last_valid_index()) - 1)).T
```

but not solving my purpose. Can anyone have better suggestion how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom lambda function in [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with convert values to sets and remove missing values, `next` is for add default values `np.nan` if `out` is empty set:

```
def f(x):
    out = set(x.dropna())
    return list(out) if len(out) > 1 else next(iter(out), np.nan)
df = df.groupby('appl_id').agg(f).reset_index()
print (df)
   appl_id  CNET  CCON           SCORE  DER  TOL_TNW
0   863283   0.0   5.0           691.0  1.9      7.3
1   863487   0.0   1.0  [761.5, 770.0]  0.6      2.6
2   863793  42.6   4.0           752.0  0.4      1.8
3   900555   NaN   NaN           650.0  0.0      NaN
```

Comment: But what if there are different values in the particular column within a group. I have updated the question.